# In WM_RBUTTONUP, does MK_RBUTTON really mean the SHIFT key is down? what?

Tags: c, winapi

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646243.aspx) says that `MK_RBUTTON`, and not `MK_SHIFT`, indicates the Shift key state.

Is this correct or is this a typo? It differs from [the behavior in `WM_LBUTTONUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608.aspx).

Comment: It does look like a typo. You can test it and see what is actually done.

Comment: Pretty easy to check this I'd have thought

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I didn't have a chance to write a program to test it right now, thought someone might already know... but you just made me realize Spy++ would show this too, yeah. Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's a typo. Spy++ shows `MK_SHIFT` and not `MK_RBUTTON`.